# Establishing SQL Server connection from Winforms app on Windows Server 2003 machine

Tags: c#, windows, sql-server-2005

This question might sound a bit childish.

User needs to keep DB on server, for which he has bought a HP Server machine, another terminal will be added to this server on which my Winforms application will be installed. So I need to know which operating system should I advise him to installed, Windows Server 2003/2008, or just normal WIN XP, and do the normal networking by sharing the terminals, so that my SQL Server 2005 database gets installed easily.

Secondly, I need to know what changes do I need to make in my connection class if SQL Server is installed on either Windows Server 2003/2008 or WIN XP. Currently I have database and Winforms application on same machine so there was no problem my current connection is

```
public SqlConnection con = 
    new sqlConnection("server=.;database=Database1;integrated security=sspi;username=sa;password=sa");
```

If you need any other details please do let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you stuck with outdated and end of life appeoraching products?`Bad enough that you are now 4 Generations (!) behind with your database. Why not install a modern operating System?

Comment: @TomTom so can you advise what should I do in such situation?

Comment: You don't need to adapt your connection string depending on the platform the SQL Server is installed on - your connection string will just be something like `server=YourServerMachineNameHere;database=....;user Id=....;pwd=.....`. But you should decide: **either** you use `Integrated Security` (login with your current Windows credentials) - **or then** you use user id/password - do **NOT** specify both in the same connection string!

Comment: Well, I would first upgrade to a supported SQL Server and if you do that go all the way to 2012. Then - use Server 2012. Then head over to connectionstrings.com and learn what to put intt the Connection string. MAYBE realize that - well - HARDCODING (!) this dat in your class is STUPID (and yes, stupid). NEVER mix code and configuration. Put it into a config file, a registry key, whatever, NEVER EVER hardcode it. And NEVER EVER use the SA user for a program. If data gets lost, you are liable for gross neglect - for the full damage.

Comment: @TomTom I am not pretty sure though but config file used in web app, right ?? Mine is a WINFORM. So will it have one ?

Comment: CONFIG FILES are a programming construct. App.config is a .net standard - not web.config, learn to use your tools. But you can always (and I do) have your own config mechanisms. Noone in this world stops you from programming.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to adapt your connection string depending on the platform the SQL Server is installed on - that's totally irrelevant to ADO.NET.

Your connection string will just be something like

```
server=YourServerMachineNameHere;database=Database1;.......
```

Also: you need to make up your mind whether you want to use `Integrated Security` (login with your current Windows credentials)

```
server=YourServerMachineNameHere;database=Database1;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

or then you use `user id/password` for your application:

```
server=YourServerMachineNameHere;database=Database1;user id=YourAppUser;pwd=top$ecret
```

but do not specify both in the same connection string (and **NEVER EVER** use `sa` as your `user id` - just don't - don't even think about it).

[This site here](http://www.connectionstrings.com) has **tons** of examples of what connection strings will look like, what all the options are etc. - go and have a look!